# What is the reason behind the variations of quoting Deut 6:5 in Matt 22:37, Mark 12:30, and Luke 10:27?

Tags: matthew, luke, mark, deuteronomy, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

In [Deut 6:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A5%2CMatthew+22%3A37%2CMark+12%3A30%2CLuke+10%3A27&version=ESV) we read (ESV):

> You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your might.

But in [Matt 22:37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A5%2CMatthew+22%3A37%2CMark+12%3A30%2CLuke+10%3A27&version=ESV) we read (ESV):

> And he said to him, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul ***and with all your mind***.   *(omitting "with all your might")*

and in [Mark 12:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A5%2CMatthew+22%3A37%2CMark+12%3A30%2CLuke+10%3A27&version=ESV) we read (ESV):

> And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul ***and with all your mind*** and with all your strength.’

and in [Luke 10:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+6%3A5%2CMatthew+22%3A37%2CMark+12%3A30%2CLuke+10%3A27&version=ESV) we read (ESV):

> And he answered, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength ***and with all your mind***, and your neighbor as yourself.”

**What is the reason by each gospel writer for the change (indicated above in *italic*)?**